# Error when trying to show status bar for ios app

Tags: ios, swift

Just trying to show the status bar, I have the following under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation)
```

and it gives me the error, 'cannot convert value of type 'UIStatusBarAnimation.Type' to expected argument type 'UIStatusBarAnimation'

Why does the one I'm using have the .type at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in one of the actual animation values. For example:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)
```